# Search using ListView in a fragment

Tags: java, android, string, listview, switch-statement

I need help.

I'm having trouble about the function of my search bar.
Before putting the search code. My ListandSearch.java is working well. It work's the way what I wanted to do.

ListandSearch.java:

```
public class ListandSearch extends Fragment{


    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter;
    ListView listview;


    String[] esttype = {
            "Art Gallery", //1
            "ATM", //2
            "Bakery", //3
            "Bank", //4
            "Bar", //5


};


    public ListandSearch(){

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_fragment, container, false);

        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.thislist);
        inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , esttype);
        listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ArtGalleryFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new AtmFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new BakeryFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new BankFragment()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new BarFragment()).commit();
                        break;

                        default:
                        break;

                }
            }});
        return view;
    }
}
```

Then i insert this code:

```
/************************************************************************************/
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
               // getActivity().
                        listViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        /*****************************************************************/
```

So far the code is working. It can search.

The problem: (Ex. #1 I search the "complete" word Bar and select it instead it will go to the BarFragment it goes to the ArtGalleryFragment)

(Ex. #2 When I search "[ba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZuMz.png)" it display's the list bakery, bank, bar. When I select Bank instead when it goes to the BankFragment it goes to the AtmFragment.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `int position`, as it is the position in your search result list, not the complete list.

Ex 1: There's only one element in your search result, so it has index 0. Selecting it causes `case 0` to run, which is `ArtGalleryFragment`.

Ex 2: "Bank" is the second element in the search result list, and `AtmFragment` is the second case (index 1) in your `switch`.

Comment: So, what can you recommend?

Comment: You can use listen on the `listView`'s selection change rather than mouse click. It will tell you which element was selected.

Comment: Possibly also get `listView`'s `selectedItem` or `selectedIndex` in `onItemClick`, but I'm not sure whether you'll run into timing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement Filterable interface.

Comment: i'll take note of that